# Capslock remap on old PS/2 keyboard

Tags: linux, usb, keyboard, ps2-keyboard, ibm-ps2

I have an old IBM keyboard connected to my laptop with a PS/2 to USB adapter. I'm having trouble remapping the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key in Linux. Holding the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, remapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, only works for the first keyboard shortcut. Even though I'm still holding <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, every key press after that is unmodified.

Using `sudo showkey` I've found that even though I'm still holding the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, when I release another key the release code for the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is sent too.

I can't tell if this is a limitation of the keyboard or the USB adapter. The keybinding works on my laptop keyboard, just not my external one. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very similar problem, an old PS2 keyboard connected through a ps2->usb adapter and after I remapped the capslock to ctrl in Windows (both XP and Win7) I could never get the second control modified keystroke to be taken as a control character.  What I found was  after I released the first control modified character I had to release and re-depress the capslock key in order to send another ctrl character.

I had edited the registry entry for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout
and added a Scancode Map entry

I knew that the original ctrl key worked fine on the PS2 keyboard, as it would allow multiple ctrl modified chars to be typed without re-depressing the ctrl character.  I also knew that the capsLock key when remapped to ctrl char worked fine as a ctrl key when the keyboard was connected via a PS2 port to the computer.  So my conclusion was that the USB converter or connection was failing to pass the multi ctrl keystrokes.

Eventually I tried a USB keyboard connected to the USB port on the PC and I found it works fine, either with the original ctrl key or with the remapped caps-lock key.  With a working solution I did not do any further research but it seems conceivable that the problem is in the PS/2 -> USB converter I was using.